# Kaspersky fails to load

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, antivirus

I have Kaspersky installed on my Samsung Galaxy S2. Since the last update it doesn't work anymore. I get a startup screen that asks for my email address for an anti-theft account. When I fill this in (or leave it blank) and click the next bottom, the app crashes and that's it. I've tried this numerous times. I've rebooted, nothing helps.

Do you have any suggestions on how to get this working? I mailed Kaspersky about this, but am afraid that they will not offer much help.

Comment: One word - **uninstall** it! You don't need it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Avatarrom on my phone,partly because of this problem, reinstalled Kaspersky and since then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound odd, but there are not very many Android viruses. My Android system still has never caught a virus and I spend a lot of time on the Internet. You may be better not having Android anti-virus applications.